# tempfile.TemporaryFile vs. StringIO

Tags: python, stringio, cstringio

I've written a little benchmark where i compare different string concatenating methods for [ZOCache](https://github.com/webmeisterei/ZOCache).

So it looks here like tempfile.TemporaryFile is faster than anything else:

```
$ python src/ZOCache/tmp_benchmark.py 
3.00407409668e-05 TemporaryFile
0.385630846024 SpooledTemporaryFile
0.299962997437 BufferedRandom
0.0849719047546 io.StringIO
0.113346099854 concat
```

The benchmark code i've been using:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from __future__ import print_function
import io
import timeit
import tempfile


class Error(Exception):
    pass


def bench_temporaryfile():
    with tempfile.TemporaryFile(bufsize=10*1024*1024) as out:
        for i in range(0, 100):
            out.write(b"Value = ")
            out.write(bytes(i))
            out.write(b" ")

        # Get string.
        out.seek(0)
        contents = out.read()
        out.close()
        # Test first letter.
        if contents[0:5] != b"Value":
            raise Error


def bench_spooledtemporaryfile():
    with tempfile.SpooledTemporaryFile(max_size=10*1024*1024) as out:
        for i in range(0, 100):
            out.write(b"Value = ")
            out.write(bytes(i))
            out.write(b" ")

        # Get string.
        out.seek(0)
        contents = out.read()
        out.close()
        # Test first letter.
        if contents[0:5] != b"Value":
            raise Error


def bench_BufferedRandom():
    # 1. BufferedRandom
    with io.open('out.bin', mode='w+b') as fp:
        with io.BufferedRandom(fp, buffer_size=10*1024*1024) as out:
            for i in range(0, 100):
                out.write(b"Value = ")
                out.write(bytes(i))
                out.write(b" ")

            # Get string.
            out.seek(0)
            contents = out.read()
            # Test first letter.
            if contents[0:5] != b'Value':
                raise Error


def bench_stringIO():
    # 1. Use StringIO.
    out = io.StringIO()
    for i in range(0, 100):
        out.write(u"Value = ")
        out.write(unicode(i))
        out.write(u" ")

    # Get string.
    contents = out.getvalue()
    out.close()
    # Test first letter.
    if contents[0] != 'V':
        raise Error


def bench_concat():
    # 2. Use string appends.
    data = ""
    for i in range(0, 100):
        data += u"Value = "
        data += unicode(i)
        data += u" "
    # Test first letter.
    if data[0] != u'V':
        raise Error


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(str(timeit.timeit('bench_temporaryfile()', setup="from __main__ import bench_temporaryfile", number=1000)) + " TemporaryFile")
    print(str(timeit.timeit('bench_spooledtemporaryfile()', setup="from __main__ import bench_spooledtemporaryfile", number=1000)) + " SpooledTemporaryFile")
    print(str(timeit.timeit('bench_BufferedRandom()', setup="from __main__ import bench_BufferedRandom", number=1000)) + " BufferedRandom")
    print(str(timeit.timeit("bench_stringIO()", setup="from __main__ import bench_stringIO", number=1000)) + " io.StringIO")
    print(str(timeit.timeit("bench_concat()", setup="from __main__ import bench_concat", number=1000)) + " concat")
```

**EDIT Python3.4.3 + io.BytesIO**

```
python3 ./src/ZOCache/tmp_benchmark.py 
2.689500024644076e-05 TemporaryFile
0.30429405899985795 SpooledTemporaryFile
0.348170792000019 BufferedRandom
0.0764778530001422 io.BytesIO
0.05162201000030109 concat
```

New source with io.BytesIO:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
from __future__ import print_function
import io
import timeit
import tempfile


class Error(Exception):
    pass


def bench_temporaryfile():
    with tempfile.TemporaryFile() as out:
        for i in range(0, 100):
            out.write(b"Value = ")
            out.write(bytes(str(i), 'utf-8'))
            out.write(b" ")

        # Get string.
        out.seek(0)
        contents = out.read()
        out.close()
        # Test first letter.
        if contents[0:5] != b"Value":
            raise Error


def bench_spooledtemporaryfile():
    with tempfile.SpooledTemporaryFile(max_size=10*1024*1024) as out:
        for i in range(0, 100):
            out.write(b"Value = ")
            out.write(bytes(str(i), 'utf-8'))
            out.write(b" ")

        # Get string.
        out.seek(0)
        contents = out.read()
        out.close()
        # Test first letter.
        if contents[0:5] != b"Value":
            raise Error


def bench_BufferedRandom():
    # 1. BufferedRandom
    with io.open('out.bin', mode='w+b') as fp:
        with io.BufferedRandom(fp, buffer_size=10*1024*1024) as out:
            for i in range(0, 100):
                out.write(b"Value = ")
                out.write(bytes(i))
                out.write(b" ")

            # Get string.
            out.seek(0)
            contents = out.read()
            # Test first letter.
            if contents[0:5] != b'Value':
                raise Error


def bench_BytesIO():
    # 1. Use StringIO.
    out = io.BytesIO()
    for i in range(0, 100):
        out.write(b"Value = ")
        out.write(bytes(str(i), 'utf-8'))
        out.write(b" ")

    # Get string.
    contents = out.getvalue()
    out.close()
    # Test first letter.
    if contents[0:5] != b'Value':
        raise Error


def bench_concat():
    # 2. Use string appends.
    data = ""
    for i in range(0, 100):
        data += "Value = "
        data += str(i)
        data += " "
    # Test first letter.
    if data[0] != 'V':
        raise Error


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(str(timeit.timeit('bench_temporaryfile()', setup="from __main__ import bench_temporaryfile", number=1000)) + " TemporaryFile")
    print(str(timeit.timeit('bench_spooledtemporaryfile()', setup="from __main__ import bench_spooledtemporaryfile", number=1000)) + " SpooledTemporaryFile")
    print(str(timeit.timeit('bench_BufferedRandom()', setup="from __main__ import bench_BufferedRandom", number=1000)) + " BufferedRandom")
    print(str(timeit.timeit("bench_BytesIO()", setup="from __main__ import bench_BytesIO", number=1000)) + " io.BytesIO")
    print(str(timeit.timeit("bench_concat()", setup="from __main__ import bench_concat", number=1000)) + " concat")
```

Is that true for every platform? And if so why?

**EDIT: Results with fixed benchmark (and fixed code):**

```
0.2675984420002351 TemporaryFile
0.28104681999866443 SpooledTemporaryFile
0.3555715570000757 BufferedRandom
0.10379689100045653 io.BytesIO
0.05650951399911719 concat
```

Comment: `GROANMODE=1` You didn't actually run the temporary file test, it should be `timeit('bench_temporaryfile()'` (with the parens to call the function).

Comment: @tdelaney: Nice catch. Should have noticed how suspicious the timing was there, but I just assumed my archaic system didn't do temporary files efficiently. :-) I incorporated that into my answer (and made it the primary issue, because it is).

Comment: Thank you @tdelaney and ShadowRanger.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your biggest problem: [Per tdelaney](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35278482/tempfile-temporaryfile-vs-stringio/35278713?noredirect=1#comment58270931_35278482), you never actually ran the `TemporaryFile` test; you omitted the parens in the `timeit` snippet (and only for that test, the others actually ran). So you were timing the time taken to lookup the name `bench_temporaryfile`, but not to actually call it. Change:

```
print(str(timeit.timeit('bench_temporaryfile', setup="from __main__ import bench_temporaryfile", number=1000)) + " TemporaryFile")
```

to:

```
print(str(timeit.timeit('bench_temporaryfile()', setup="from __main__ import bench_temporaryfile", number=1000)) + " TemporaryFile")
```

(adding parens to make it a call) to fix.

Some other issues:

`io.StringIO` is fundamentally different from your other test cases. Specifically, all the other types you're testing with operate in binary mode, reading and writing `str`, and avoiding line ending conversions. `io.StringIO` uses Python 3 style strings (`unicode` in Python 2), which your tests acknowledge by using different literals and converting to `unicode` instead of `bytes`. This adds a lot of encoding and decoding overhead, as well as using a lot more memory (`unicode` uses 2-4x the memory of `str` for the same data, which means more allocator overhead, more copy overhead, etc.).

The other major difference is that you're setting a truly huge `bufsize` for `TemporaryFile`; few system calls would need to occur, and most writes are just appending to contiguous memory in the buffer. By contrast, `io.StringIO` is storing the individual values written, and only joining them together when you ask for them with `getvalue()`.

Also, lastly, you think you're being forward compatible by using the `bytes` constructor, but you're not; in Python 2 `bytes` is an alias for `str`, so `bytes(10)` returns `'10'`, but in Python 3, `bytes` is a totally different thing, and passing an integer to it returns a zero initialized `bytes` object of that size, `bytes(10)` returns `b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'`.

If you want a fair test case, at the very least switch to `cStringIO.StringIO` or `io.BytesIO` instead of `io.StringIO` and write `bytes` uniformly. Typically, you wouldn't explicitly set the buffer size for `TemporaryFile` and the like yourself, so you might consider dropping that.

In my own tests on Linux x64 with Python 2.7.10, using ipython's `%timeit` magic, the ranking is:

1. `io.BytesIO` ~48 μs per loop
2. `io.StringIO` ~54 μs per loop (so `unicode` overhead didn't add much)
3. `cStringIO.StringIO` ~83 μs per loop
4. `TemporaryFile` ~2.8 *ms* per loop (note units; ms is 1000x longer than μs)

And that's without going back to default buffer sizes (I kept the explicit `bufsize` from your tests). I suspect the behavior of `TemporaryFile` will vary a lot more (depending on the OS and how temporary files are handled; some systems might just store in memory, others might store in `/tmp`, but of course, `/tmp` might just be a RAMdisk anyway).

Something tells me you may have a setup where the `TemporaryFile` is basically a plain memory buffer that never goes to the file system, where mine may be ultimately ending up on persistent storage (if only for short periods); stuff happening in memory is predictable, but when you involve the file system (which `TemporaryFile` can, depending on OS, kernel settings, etc.), the behavior will differ a great deal between systems.

Comment: Can you please give the code of your tests? Wann see what i'm doing different/wrong.

Comment: @pcdummy: I doubt your tests are wrong, but I'm guessing we have very different under-the-hood behaviors for `TemporaryFile`; you're probably on Linux kernel 3.11 or higher (where `O_TMPFILE` is available and does something meaningful to minimize actual disk I/O); I'm on an older kernel without that feature, so I create a real file in `/tmp`. My code is nigh identical to yours (I just dropped the tests for `BufferedRandom` and `SpooledTemporaryFile`) defined at the interactive prompt and tested with the `%timeit` magic from `ipython`, e.g. `%timeit -r5 bench_temporaryfile()`.

Comment: See the [`open` manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html) and read the info on `O_TMPFILE`, which likely makes a huge difference in performance between our OSes.

Comment: i tested on 3.2.0-4-amd64 (Debian wheezy) tempfile is also a lot faster there. No tmpfs mount on /tmp.

Comment: @pcdummy: You may want to try manually performing the same tasks [as the built-in `tempfile.TemporaryFile`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/0e7aabe76159/Lib/tempfile.py#l570) and see if it actually ends up supporting `O_TMPFILE` or otherwise doing something special. I suspect my system is both old and does silly things (out of date RHEL version, with almost the whole system mounted over NFS). Point is, at least on some systems, `TemporaryFile` is going to end up changing cost a lot just because it might end up using a slow disk, not memory buffers.

Comment: @pcdummy: Oh, and [as tdelaney points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35278482/tempfile-temporaryfile-vs-stringio/35278713?noredirect=1#comment58270931_35278482), you omitted the parens when testing `TemporaryFile`, so you never actually ran a thing; add parens to the call in the `timeit` test.