# What are the differences between tempfile module and IO file-like objects

Tags: python-3.x, temporary-files, stringio, bytesio

I have found that there are a lot of similarities between both modules in the area of creating temp files using `io.BytesIO()` or `io.StringIo()` and `tempfile.TemporaryFile()`
What is the purpose of each one ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`io.BytesIO()` create a file-like object linked to a **memory area**, and should be used to store **binary data** (like data used to represent an image, a music, a MS Word document, etc.).

`io.StringIO()` create a file-like object linked to a **memory area**, and should be used to store **text data** (like a html page, a php script, etc).

`tempfile.TemporaryFile()` create a temp file **on the disk** (not in memory). Use first argument `mode` to specify or not the `b` flag to determine if the file should store binary data or only text.

Comment: TemporaryFile here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35278482/tempfile-temporaryfile-vs-stringio as you can see in the last two paragraphs of the answer he said it depends on the OS, so I think that there are something else behind creating this module

Comment: This is because on Unix systems (macOS, Linux) you can mount `/tmp` directory in RAMdisk. This kind of config put files into RAM instead of filesystem when copied in `/tmp`. This is done at OS level and is not related to Python tools.

Comment: after reading docs a little bit, I have found that it uses the disk storage, And I am going to discover more about its functionalities